# Trying to understand my Google Analytics exit pages

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to understand my Google Analytics because it is showing me landing and exit pages from my site which are the same, and broken, but I don't understand how users are coming to these pages that seem to have part of the link from my YouTube account.
Here is what I am seeing

[image: my google analytics exit pages for russlaw.co.uk]

this is the link to my youtube account. 
https://www.youtube.com/user/russandnela

and as we can see it has this part on the end  `/user/russandnela`

But I can't work out why people would be hitting my site. If anyone wants to take a look and try to help that would be fantastic.

Comment: Since this is not code-related this if off-topic for stackoverflow. You might consider asking this at webmasters.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: thank you. that is helpful. I shall do that now. shall I remove this comment from here?